# iOS Multiple Sign in Dropbox Accounts

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to link and essentially sign into multiple Dropbox accounts for iOS (using Objective-C)? I looked at the Dropbox API and I can successfully log into one account. I would  like to extend this functionality to support multiple accounts for a single user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is possible in both the [Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios) and [Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios). Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: How/Where exactly do I begin?

Comment: How about those links I sent you? It's hard to get you anything more specific without knowing which API you're using... but both those pages should link you to a tutorial. Authenticating multiple accounts should be largely the same as authenticating a single account.

Comment: Where are the links you've sent me? I solely want to use the Dropbox API and anything else that would get the job done.

Comment: The two links in my answer. (Core API and Sync API)